# About helper method on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to learn Ruby on Rails from [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/basic_login?version=5.1#ch).
But I have one problem on chapter 7 list 8.29, why can I use `@current_user` in `app/helpers/sessionse_helper` `log_out` method?

```
module SessionHelper

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

If anyone knows this function, please tell me.

Comment: You don't "use" it there. You simply set an instance variable, which is what you can do in most (all?) places in ruby. What exactly is your confusion here?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I believe “instance variable,” which is shared across _different method_ is confusing. Rails literally enforces using instance variables, while they are in 99% cases a code smell and a first class citizens in error-proneness.

Comment: You can use instance variables because you have a brand new controller instance for each HTTP request, and that controller instance serves ONLY that request. If you don't like it, maybe Phoenix is a better framework for you, but it uses Elixir language.

Answer (score 0):

@current_user used to set the logged in user in the application. Once you are logged out from the application, log_out method setting it to nil so that it is not accessible anywhere within the application hence make it complete logout.